# What is the most common collocation to describe the seven trumpets blown in Revelation?

Tags: collocation, religion

[Revelation 8:1-2](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation+8%3A1-2&version=KJV) (of the Bible) says the following (KJV):

> And when he had opened the seventh seal, there was silence in heaven about the space of half an hour.
>   And I saw the seven angels which stood before God; and to them were given seven trumpets.

I want a concise way to refer to these seven trumpets. Options I have considered include:

- the seven trumpets of Revelation
- the seven trumpet blasts of Revelation

(or substitute "the Apocalypse" for "Revelation" in either case).

**Is any of these phrases the most common collocation for describing the event mentioned in Revelation 8:1-2; if so, which one; and if not, what is?** If it matters, assume some variety of British English or General American English, as suits you.

Note: for my use case, the collocation must include a reference to both an instrument being blown and an allusion to Christian eschatology. Other aspects (e.g. the number of instruments; the specific name of the instrument; etc.) are negotiable.

Comment: There are 870 000 Google hits (at my space-time coordinates) for "seven trumpets" and, ignoring adverts (which probably use the collocation for effect anyway) I haven't found a non-relevant one as far as I've bothered looking. I don't think I'd reduce 'the seven trumpets of Revelation' to 'the seven trumpets' if the previous conversation had centred on when to fill up the car before Christmas, though.

Comment: Given the predominance of the collocation "The Four Horsemen of the Apocalypse", I'd go for something similar with the Seven Trumpets of the Apocalypse too. And maybe even capital letters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The great judgments of the Tribulation consist of seven seals, which were attached to the "title deed" to the earth.  In that deed, which only the Lamb is found worthy to open, are all the events that would transpire before God brings history to a close with His destruction of the old heavens and earth and the creation of the new heavens and the new earth. Within the seventh seal are the judgments of both the seven trumpets and the seven bowls, with the judgments of the seven bowls coming after the seventh angel sounds the seventh trumpet.

In other words, you have

> - one scroll
> - seven seals, which seal up all the judgments of the entire Tribulation period
> - the seventh seal consists of the judgments of the seven trumpets, followed by the judgments of the seven bowls
> - the seventh trumpet signals the pouring out of the first bowl, which is followed by the pouring out of the second-through-the-seventh bowls

How best to collocate just the judgments of the seven trumpets and what transpires after each successive trumpet is sounded (or blown) is a little tricky, especially since the seventh trumpet is not a judgment, per se, but rather it announces seven subsequent judgments which in turn usher in the denouement.

Compounding the difficulty is that within "Christian eschatology," as you put it, there are probably a dozen or more mutually-exclusive ways of looking at the ordering of the events and  chronology of the Great Tribulation. Some Christians (though I am not one of them) believe our 2013 world is now experiencing some part or aspect of that Great Tribulation.

Perhaps the simplest ploy is to call the judgments of the seven trumpets exactly that, but with a few extra words:

> "The Sounding of the Judgments of the Seven Trumpets During the Great Tribulation of the Apocalypse."

There are, by the way, other trumpets both in John's book and elsewhere in the New Testament (e.g., Rev 1:10 and 4:1; the trumpet of God in 1 Cor 15:52 and 1 Thess 4:16; and other trumpets mentioned elsewhere, as in Heb. 12:19). Moreover, the judgment of the seventh trumpet subsumes the seven judgments of the seven bowls. What to do, what to do?
I leave it to you.